# What word did the Germans use for "Buchstabe" before print was invented?

Tags: etymology

I've often wondered about this. "Buchstabe" obviously(?) derives from the letters used in the early printing presses (think Gutenberg). What did they call a letter before Gutenberg?

[image]

**update**
Seems my assumption was wrong and it wasn't obvious after all. (Lucky that I added the question mark.) Thanks for the answers.

Comment: That'll print backwards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, the etymology of "Buchstabe" doesn't have anything to do with printing presses:

> **Herkunft:**
>   wahrscheinlich aus dem Germanischen: *bōks - Runenstäbchen (die unter Anderem aus Buchenholz gefertigt wurden) und *stab - senkrechter Strich in der Rune. ([German wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Buchstabe))
>
> **Etymology**
>   From Middle High German buochstap, from Old High German buohstab (“letter, writing”). From Proto-Germanic *bōkastabaz, from Proto-Indo-European roots *bʰagós (“book”) + *stěbʰ, *stemb (“support, stamp, be astonished”). Compare English bookstaff, bookstave. ([English wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Buchstabe))

This etymological explanation suggests that the word "Buchstabe" has been in use much longer than since the time of Gutenberg.

Comment: Ops. I have told several people the Gutenberg version :D... I should have looked it up. It just seemed so logical

Answer (score 13):

Simple answer: *Buchstabe*.

In ancient times, runes (the first letters in use for most Germanic languages) were carved into thin wood, often beech wood (German *Buche*).

The German words *Buchstabe* and *Buch* derive from the name of this tree, as does the English word "book". The same is true for the Nordic languages.

The word *Buch* was used for books already before they were printed.